# Does AWS Cognito only use OAuth2.0 / OIDC for authentication / authorization mechanism?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I have a React SPA and I have a custom login page. Currently we are on a AWS and we use AWS Cognito to get access token.

Basically when the user first visit the website and when the front end code is loaded in his browser, it quickly judges that there is no access token. Therefore only the custom login page is rendered.

Then the user inputs his password and username, and then an access token and an ID token are returned from AWS Cognito. Here is the code:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

...

// login 
const user = await Auth.signIn(formData.username, formData.password);
```

Now since the tokens are present in the browser, the frontend code will render the user dashboard. When user interacts on the dashboard, all backend API calls will have the access token attached.

I was told that by doing the above, I am using a thing called ROPC, Resource Owner Password Credentials, which is strongly criticized and will be removed in OAuth2.1.

I have a few questions:

1. Am I doing ROPC here?
2. Basically, I just need a way to secure my SPA and the Backend Web APIs the SPA is calling. I just need something that can issue JWT access tokens. OAuth2/OIDC is not the only thing that can issue JWT tokens, right? What are other authentication mechanisms are there that can issue JWT?
3. Do I even need OAuth2.0 / OIDC? Am I using it in the wrong context?
4. Does AWS Cognito only employ OAuth2 / OIDC? does it support any other mechanisms?